# How to trigger click in ng-repeat in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to trigger an event click handler in angular (click the button and trigger also the span). I tried to use **nth-child** selector but still no results. Any suggestions ? I tried also with jQuery selector ...

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptongalex/LmL8ehvd/2/)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h3 ng-bind="version"></h3>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <button ng-click="forceClick(item,$index)">Click</button>
      <span ng-bind='item.name' ng-click='showMsg(item.name)'></span>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
</div>


angular.module('app',[])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$timeout){
$scope.version = 'Angular 1.4.8';
$scope.items = [];
$scope.showMsg = showMsg;
$scope.forceClick = forceClick;

init();

function forceClick(item, index){
 $timeout(function(){
    angular.element('#wrapper ul li:eq(' + index + ')  span').triggerHandler('click');
 },3000);
}

function showMsg(itemName){
  alert("Clicked on " + itemName);
};

function init(){
 for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $scope.items.push({
    name:'item ' + i,
    selected:false
  });
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this controller :)

```
   angular.module('app', []).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.version = 'Angular 1.4.8';
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.showMsg = showMsg;
        $scope.forceClick = forceClick;

        init();

        $scope.showMsg = function(itemName) {
            alert("Clicked on " + itemName);
        };
        $scope.forceClick = function(item, index) {
            console.log('I clicked !!');
        };

        function init() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                $scope.items.push({
                    name:'item ' + i,
                    selected:false
                });
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I have it top : $scope.forceClick = forceClick;

Answer (score 1):

try to inject `$scope` in the controller

```
.controller('MainCtrl', '$scope', function($scope, $timeout) {
```

Any examples?

Comment: that is not valid, you define the controller in 2 most-used ways, .controller('name',['$scope',function($scope){ //code }]) with the purpose of resolving minification conflicts, or .controller('name',ctrlName); ctrlName.$inject = ['$scope']; function ctrlName($scope){ //code } ; If the "$scope" hasn't been injected, my binding wouldn't bind / work also :P